# Camel 3 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultComponent

Tags: java, apache-camel

No Class Def Found exception while sending the Exchange in Camel 3. 
Application throws NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultComponent.

Stack Trace Below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultComponent
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2419) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:865) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1334) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.doLoadClass(ObjectHelper.java:474) ~[camel-util-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.loadClass(ObjectHelper.java:378) ~[camel-util-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.loadClass(ObjectHelper.java:355) ~[camel-util-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultClassResolver.loadClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:126) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultClassResolver.resolveClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:52) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultFactoryFinder.newInstance(DefaultFactoryFinder.java:133) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultFactoryFinder.access$100(DefaultFactoryFinder.java:40) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultFactoryFinder$1.get(DefaultFactoryFinder.java:86) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultFactoryFinder$2.apply(DefaultFactoryFinder.java:172) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultFactoryFinder$2.apply(DefaultFactoryFinder.java:168) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultFactoryFinder.addToClassMap(DefaultFactoryFinder.java:168) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultFactoryFinder.findClass(DefaultFactoryFinder.java:83) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultFactoryFinder.findClass(DefaultFactoryFinder.java:75) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultComponentResolver.findComponent(DefaultComponentResolver.java:82) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultComponentResolver.resolveComponent(DefaultComponentResolver.java:55) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.initComponent(AbstractCamelContext.java:548) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.access$000(AbstractCamelContext.java:165) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext$2.apply(AbstractCamelContext.java:476) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext$2.apply(AbstractCamelContext.java:472) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getComponent(AbstractCamelContext.java:472) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getComponent(AbstractCamelContext.java:450) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:715) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.resolveMandatoryEndpoint(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:493) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:123) ~[camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    at com.ezops.aro.workflow.service.WorkflowRouter.process(WorkflowRouter.java:77) ~[aro-workflow-4.2.1-OS-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63) ~[camel-support-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: make a sure version of the third party api. Check jar is in your classpath? check duplicate jar are present in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

DefaultComponent has been moved to a new package and artifact in Camel 3 so it looks like you have a custom component that has not bee adapter to Camel 3.

Can you share some more info about your project ?